# GWTTestCase file upload

Tags: gwt, file-upload

I am trying to write some gwt testcases to upload files using FileUpload and FormPanel.

My code (unttested) looks like:

```java
@Test
public void testImportXml() {
    delayTestFinish(10000);
    FormPanel fileForm=new FormPanel();
    fileForm.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
    fileForm.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
    fileForm.setAction(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()+"/xmlupload");
    URL myFile=this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("myfile.xml");
    // FileUpload uploadField; ??

    fileForm.addSubmitHandler(new SubmitHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSubmit(SubmitEvent event) {
            logger.info("submit handler pushed");
        }
    });
    fileForm.submit();
}
```

I could not find a method to configure FileUpload to use "myFile".
I understood that this is done for browser-security reasons, but it is a massive obstacle when writing testcases.

Does there exist a way to specify filenames for FileUpload for testcases within gwt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

But then one could wonder what is it that you're actually trying to test?

- the submit / submit-complete handlers? You'd better fire the events directly at the FormPanel; you could also refactor your code to use some MV* pattern so that the code you're actually testing is not tied to GWT widgets, then you can use a vanilla JUnit test.
- the servlet? Then don't use a GWTTestCase, use HttpClient or anything similar and make a request against your servlet, running in a server (best done as an *integration test*; have a look at [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org) to make it easier to setup)
- the whole interaction between the FormPanel+FileUpload and servlet? Then don't use a GWTTestCase, use Selenium to drive a browser talking to a running server (best done as an *integration test* or *acceptance test*)

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. Whilst I agree with your comments, I don't like that I have to start using a lot of infrastructure at an early stage in my first gwt-project to test a simple client-server interaction.

Comment: It depends what you want to test. If testing the server-side, you could also refactor your code so that the _real_ processing can run independent from a servlet container (i.e. extract the file and fields from the request and pass them as arguments to another method, and unit-test that method only, so you don't need an `HttpServletRequest`, `HttpServletResponse`, etc.) But if you want to test the whole interaction, the Selenium is what you need/want, with the added bonus that you can drive real browsers too! (see http://saucelabs.com for instance, for complete automation)